# Difference between Client.CreateDocumentAsync( ) and documents.AddAsync( );

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have one Azure Function which is adding documents to cosmos db. One way of adding is by creating a cosmos client and then calling client.CreateDocumentAsync( ) and other is creating an Output binding to Azure Function with IAsyncCollector documents and then calling documents.AddAsync().

I would like to know what's the difference between these two and which one is more preferable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Two main differences:

- Output binding maintains a single static instance of the client across executions. When you are calling `client.CreateDocumentAsync` you are in charge of maintaining the client instance, and the recommendation is to follow the [singleton pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections#static-clients) to avoid opening multiple connections and not sharing them across executions.
- Output binding actually does a UpsertDocumentAsync when AddAsync is called on the IAsyncCollector, you can check the source code: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB/Bindings/CosmosDBAsyncCollector.cs#L28

Comment: but we have client.CreateDocumentAsync and client.UpdateDocumentAsync() and same is not true for output binding... is that on purpose i.e. we do not have any thing like document.UpdateAsync(). I was reading more on it, and got this point :)

Comment: You have client.CreateDocument, client.ReplaceDocument, and client.UpsertDocument, there is no client.Update. The limitation is that the interface (IAsyncCollector) that the Functions bindings have does not have any other methods other than AddAsync. So the safest option I guess was to use Upsert (just inferring the author's original intent, I didn't write it).